# Using models package to manage multiple models in Django but migration cannot be generated

Tags: python, django, django-models

I followed the steps in the documentation but couldn't succeed.
What do I need to do to generate migration files?
I try to put all models in models.py and it can be generated

apartment/models/__init__.py：

```py
from .water_bill import WaterBill
from .electricity_bill import ElectricityBill
```

Directory Structure

```
apartment/
    views.py
    __init__.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        electricity_bill.py
        water_bill.py
```

Script executed

```
python manage.py makemigrations apartment
```

then show “No changes detected in app 'apartment'"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the imported models to the `__all__` list of `__init__.py`?

here is an example:

```py
    from .water_bill import WaterBill
    from .electricity_bill import ElectricityBill
    
    __all__ = ['WaterBill','ElectricityBill']
```

then try running the migration again

hope this helps

Comment: I tried but still can't detect

Comment: is the app included in the settings file under  `installed_apps`

Comment: Yes, it was added in the first step.